# Make does not compile under windows - Cmake, Msys, MinGW

Tags: makefile, cmake, mingw, msys2, opencascade

I am following this guide in order to build Opencascade frmo source:

https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/blob/master/BUILD.MINGWw64.md

I have done everything up to the MSYS part.
The CMake configuration and generation was succesfull.
I now have a folder with all the things that CMake generated.

So i start MSYS2, and i cd into that directory.
Then i type `make`.

This is what i get:

```
User1@User1-PC MSYS ~/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD
$ make
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User1\Desktop\OpenCascade project\oce\BUILD>
```

As you can see, nothing happens, no compilation. There is a prompt for me to type. But nothing gets executed.

EDIT:

*I redid the proccess in a new directory, so that no space characters exist in my directory. Problem still remains.

*When i run `make --version`, i get this:

```
$ make --version 
GNU Make 4.3 Built for x86_64-pc-msys Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

*When i exit the prompt (CONTROL + C) i get this:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\OPENCAS\oce\BUILD>make: *** [Makefile:1734: cmake_check_build_system] Interrupt
```

*These are the contents of the makefile, line 1734:

```
$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
```

*When i run `make VERBOSE=1`, i get this:

```
User1@User1-PC MSYS ~/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/BUILD
$ make VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\User1\Desktop\OPENCAS\oce -BC:\Users\User1\Desktop\OPENCAS\oce\BUILD --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Perhaps, the space in your path is causing an issue.

Comment: Are you running the correct make? Do you have it aliased?  What does `make --version` return?  Something seems wrong with your build environment when you go from an MSYS like prompt to a `cmd.exe` like prompt.

Comment: $ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: The problem is that make is invoking a shell without a command, so you get an interactive shell.  If you exit from that prompt, what happens?  I agree with @squareskittles you should _never_ use paths containing whitespace when dealing with software development, most particularly with `make` but in general it's a bad idea regardless of the development environment you use.

Comment: I will redo it in a dir witout spaces and i will report here.

Comment: @MadScientist This is what happens when i exit that prompt:
"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\OPENCAS\oce\BUILD>make: *** [Makefile:1734: cmake_check_build_system] Interrupt
". Also, i redid it without spaces and the problem remains.

Comment: @squareskittles. I redid it without spaces, still the problem remains.

Comment: Well, the problem is obviously with the `cmake_check_build_system` rule at line 1734 of the `Makefile`.  You can try posting that rule here to see if anyone can help but it seems like a configuration issue to me.  I don't use Windows so I can't really say more than that...

Comment: @MadScientist This is line 1734. "$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0"

Comment: You can run `make VERBOSE=1` and it will print all the commands with the variables expanded.  BTW, please edit your question to add info like this rather than adding it in comments, where it cannot be formatted correctly.

Comment: @MadScientist I edited the question and included all the history. In the last inclusion, is what happens when i run make VERBOSE=1.

Comment: Thanks, that's good.  Hopefully someone can understand the problem: as I said I don't work on Windows so I'm not sure what to say.  One thing I'll say is that it's highly unusual to see backslashes in paths used by makefiles.  Make and makefiles were originated on POSIX systems where the directory separator is a forward-slash, and backslashes are considered escaping characters and removed by the shell.  If there's anyplace in the configuration of this system where it asks you to enter a path, try using forward-slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: Another thing to consider is running `cmake` from within an msys shell, rather than from a Windows command terminal, if you didn't do that already.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks. I had already invoked cmake-gui from within msys2.

Comment: I don't think it causes your problem, but building in `MSYS` mode (as indicated by your terminal prompt) is probably not what you want, it involves linking against MSYS2's fork of cygwin libraries. You should restart the terminal using `mingw64.exe` (so the mode will be `MINGW64`, meaning no cygwin libs), and redo everything. (`MINGW64` is for 64-bit applications. There's also `MINGW32` for 32-bit ones.)

Comment: Tip: ninja works a lot faster than make, maybe you can try to have CMake generate ninja build files.

Comment: @BrechtSanders The question was not about speed, was it?

Comment: What @MadScientist has written is right: no backslashes are expected in a correct setup for MSYS2 builds. When I run make in MSYS2 the output looks like this: `$ make VERBOSE=1
"/C/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -S/C/Libraries/OpenCASCADE/oce...`. How could it have happened that you have backslashes in your path configurations?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I dont have a clue. Can i do something about it?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no more ideas... :-(

Comment: If you told CMake to generate "MSYS Makefiles" there should be no slashes. If you tell it to generate "Ninja" build files these do use backslashes, but ninja works fine in MSYS.

Comment: I have to add that this time i used the MSYS makefiles with the default native compilers and the cmopilation process started. I don't know why previously it would fail, i am assuming some erroneous path configuration. Although it failed at 1%.  I want to thank everybody for their useful contributions.